# How to map a route in Pivotal Cloud Foundry to a landing page

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I want PCF **(Pivotal Cloud Foundry)** route to a landing page. I have an application called `app-service`, it has a landing page which can be accessed by the link `localhost:8080/app-service/info`. How can I configure in Manifest.yml file for PCF so that simply clicking on route which is available in Pivotal Cloud Foundry **AppsManager** Dashboard to a landing page.
Currently after making deployment in PCF, when I click the link (which is route) in dashboard page, it say `Whitelabel Error Page`. So the requirement is to redirect PCF route to a landing page in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map routes to your app:

1. Go to the app `Overview` page.
2. In the panel on the left side of the page, under `Networking`, click `Routes`.
3. To add a new route, click `Map a Route`.
4. Enter the route and click `Map`.
5. Under `Choose Protocol`, select either `HTTP1` or `HTTP2`.

Based on: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-Application-Service/3.0/tas-for-vms/manage-apps.html

If you want to map a route during deployment add following to the `manifest.yml`:

```
routes:
  - route: pcf-host.your-domain.com/app-service/info
```

Based on: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#routes

Comment: thanks a lot Sir, I was able to do as you suggested in the dashboard page. I will try in `Manifest.yml` file. Accepting the valuable answer provided by you.